# Instalar Memcache no xammp para mac

Tags: php

Como posso instalar o Memcache do PHP no meu mac? eu uso Xampp e preciso desse recurso..

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro de tudo, instale o homebrew, gerenciador de dependências do MAC, com esse comando:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

depois rode o comando:

```
brew install memcached
```

Comment: ta, e depois???

Comment: Sua pergunta era como instalar o memcached e não como utilizar.